# Telerik OpenAccess cross configuration file reference problem?

Tags: telerik, orm, openaccess

I have 2 libraries and one of them is a core library with some core persistent objects such as Person, Address, etc.  I have another library which contains some different persistent objects that need to reference the core objects as well.

When I try to map them using Telerik Forward Mapping, I get a complaint that I am referencing a *"Non-Persistent Class or Non-Supported"* type.  I have added the `<reference>` tags to this library referencing the core library but that doesn't help.

So does anyone know if it is possible to reference persistent objects mapped via a different configuration file in another library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a problem in the xml that was generated for the references.  The admins at Telerik had me remove the reference id and everything then began working.